# My Games folder has been turned into a program file and is no longer a directory

Tags: directory, external-hdd, file-type

As stated in the title, I went to my games directory today, located on an external drive, which I hadn't used in a long time and found that it is no longer a directory but instead has turned into a program file and the size says "?" instead of the amount of items. The data does not seem to have been deleted as the drive is still very full, but I'm unsure as to how to change this back into a directory and get to my files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check the file system on your external drive...

- Start `gparted` and determine the partition number of the EXT4/NTFS partition that contains the games folder. I'll guess that it's /dev/sdb1. Right-click on that partition and select `unmount`.
- Start `terminal` and type:

  `fsck -f /dev/sdbX` (replacing X with the number found above)

**Update #1:**

You'll want to install `testdisk` on your main Ubuntu system disk. This is made up of `testdisk` and `photorec` which may help recovering your partition/files. In `terminal` type `man testdisk` and `man photorec` for some details. See the following website for details about testdisk...

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: I found the drive it was labelled sdj1 unmounted it, ran the command, but nothing seems to have changed, it's still a program file not a directory.

Comment: @Bencc Did fsck look like it was doing anything when it ran? Please see the update in my answer.

Comment: fsck didn't seem to do anything at all yesterday, it gave no errors


`fsck from util-linux 2.28.2
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
fsck.ext2: Not a directory while trying to open /dev/sdj1/

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>`
This is what I'm receiving today.

Comment: @Bencc Let's step back for a second. Was sdj1 an EXT4 or NTFS partition? Do you have dual-boot with Windows, and did the Games folder appear on a drive in Windows? Do you really have that many drives on your system? Show me a gparted screenshot of /dev/sdj.